# Pointer in C, don't understand how they got this result

Tags: c

here is code snippet

```
void F (int a, int *b)
{
 a = 7 ;
 *b = a ;
 b = &a ;
 *b = 4 ;
 printf("%d, %d\n", a, *b) ;
}
int main()
{
 int m = 3, n = 5;
 F(m, &n) ;
 printf("%d, %d\n", m, n) ;
 return 0;
}
```

answer

```
4 4 
3 7
```

I see how `4 4` was computed, I don't get how they got `3 7` (I do understand how 3 is computed, it is not changed since it was not passed by reference)

Thanks !

Comment: to clarify, NOTHING is passed by reference here; the second parameter is passed the address of n, by value, which is key to why this code is deliberately misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the start of `main`, we have

```
m=3   n=5  // int m = 3, n = 5;
```

then we call `F(m, &n)`, passing `m` by value, and `n` by pointer
such that

```
m = 3   n = 5
a = 3   b->n   // F(m, &n);
```

Now, inside `F()`, we assign `7` to `a`:

```
m = 3   n = 5
a = 7   b->n     // a = 7
```

then we assign `a` (=7) to the memory address pointed by `b` (->n)

```
m = 3   n = 7
a = 7   b->n     // *b = a;
```

next we change `b`, so that now `b` points to `a`:

```
m = 3   n = 7
a = 7   b->a     // b = &a;
```

and then we assign 4 to the memory address pointed by `b` (->a)

```
m = 3   n = 7
a = 4   b->a     // *b = 4;
```

printing `a` (=4) and `*b` (->a =4)

and printing `m` (=3) and `n` (=7) outside the function

Answer (score 7):

I've annotated the `F` function with comments to explain what's going on:

```
a = 7 ;  // a is now 7
*b = a ; // b points to n, so n is now 7
b = &a ; // b now points to a and no longer to n
*b = 4 ; // a is now 4. n is unaffected
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at this line

```
b = &a ;
*b = 4 ;
```

b gets the reference of a (it's memory address). When you now access *b it points to the memory of the variable a, not to n anymore

Answer (score 1):

Quite subtle indeed. :)

In `F` a lot of nonsense happens: whichever value is passed via `a`, it's discarded, and instead 7 is assigned to it. Then, the value of `a` (which is 7) is assigned to the variable to which `b` points (which is `n`, so it's here that `n` becomes 7).

At the next line, the object to which `b` points is changed, so that `b` now points to the local parameter `a`, and at the following line the object pointed by `b` (=>`a`) is set to 4.

Thus, now we have `a` that is 4, `b` that points to `a` (=>so `*b==4`, since `*b==a`), `m` is still 3 (it was passed by value, so it couldn't have been changed by `F`) and `n` was set to 7.

By the way, this is *exactly* the mess you shouldn't to *at all* in your applications to avoid confusing any people who have the disgrace to work on them. :)

Comment: Of course the whole function is non-sense. But it's the typical code examples you use in learning books and tutorials to demostrate how (in this case) pointers and references work

Comment: I know, I was just pointing out that it's not the way pointers are usually used, otherwise any C program would be an incomprehensible mess (although some people would argue that this is true :S ).